# Perl module version

Tags: perl, version, perl-module

I have a couple of perl modules installed in the `$HOME` of my web server. The web server used to run perl 5.8.8 so they were installed under `$HOME/perl/lib/perl5/5.8.8/...`

During a server migration, the web hosting company changed `perl` to `5.10.1` but I did not know about this until my scripts started failing. I managed to do a quick dirty fix by copying the `5.8.8` tree to `5.10.1` and it seems to work OK now, but I want to avoid my scripts failing like this in future.

What is the best way of allowing my scripts to use the locally stored modules under the `5.8.8` folder even if the perl version gets upgraded again?

I can add a check for the expected perl version in my scripts and email myself if it changes, but it's too late by then as the script may have failed several times before I can fix the problem. Ideally I want to prevent the scripts failing at all.

Comment: wow, they upgraded you from a 7 year old version of perl to a 3.5 year old version?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on the amount of flexibility you have when configuring your environment you may want to use [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl/).

to maintain an independent Perl installation at a specific version. This can avoid nasty surprises when the system-wide Perl installation changes.

Comment: Thanks I was just going to add that too, but you beat me.

Answer (score 5):

The thing you really should do is ensure that your needed modules are installed in the new installation. Especially for XS (C-level) modules there is no guarantee that they will run on a new version of Perl without recompiling since the core may have changed.

You should make a `Makefile.PL` or `Build.PL` which declares the dependencies of your scripts and you company should make it a policy to execute those scripts on server migration.

Finally, yes you can check `$^V` which is the running Perl. And if you do it inside a `BEGIN` block it will be executed during startup. In fact you can use local directories for your (pure perl) modules and then point to them using the [`lib`](http://p3rl.org) module.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Fortunately the modules in question are very small and not C, so I think I've got away with just copying the tree. For the time being, I've added a version number check into my upper level script that does not use the modules so that it can alert me and take other action rather than just letting the lower-level scripts fail.

Comment: If the check is in a `BEGIN` block before any `use` statements then it will still be able to take some action even before the `use`-es fail.

Answer (score 2):

Why did you move the files at all? Just keep add to PERL5LIB instead.

```
PERL5LIB=$HOME/perl/lib/perl5/5.10.1:$HOME/perl/lib/perl5/5.8.8
```

I strongly recommend that you simply use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlbrew) to install a build of Perl in your home directory instead of being at your host's mercy.